# Agregar imagen de perfil a chat con JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: swift, swift2, firebase

Estoy experimentando con JSQMessagesViewController y Firebase. He logrado guardar descargar contenido de Firebase y guardarlos por medio del chat. Hasta ahorita he tenido problemas con la imagen de perfil. Estoy declarando las siguientes dos variables:

```
var incomingAvatar: JSQMessagesAvatarImage!
var outgoingAvatar: JSQMessagesAvatarImage!
```

En mi ViewDidAppear estoy trabajando con el siguiente codigo:

```
      messageRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in
        let id = snapshot.value!["senderId"] as! String
        let text = snapshot.value!["text"] as! String
        let image = snapshot.value!["imageURL"] as! String
        let displayName = snapshot.value!["senderDisplayName"] as! String

        self.imageUrl = NSURL(string: image)
        let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: displayName, text: text)
        self.messages.append(message)
        self.finishReceivingMessage()


    }
```

En donde descargo el link de la imagen de perfil y lo convierto a NSURL

posteriormente

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
     if message.senderId == senderId {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.imageUrl!)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.incomingAvatar = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImageWithImage( UIImage(data: data!), diameter: 250)
            });
        }

                return self.incomingAvatar
    }
     else{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.imageUrl!)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.outgoingAvatar = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImageWithImage( UIImage(data: data!), diameter: 250)
            });
        }



       // self.outgoingAvatar = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImageWithImage(UIImage(named: "defaultImageCell")!, diameter: 150)
        return self.outgoingAvatar
    }




    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


}
```

Al parecer no estoy entendiendo bien el manejo de la libreria. Al correr el progama me aparece la imagen de perfil del usuario que escribe en todas las imagenes de perfil del chat y cuando otro usuario escribe algo todas las imagenes vuelven a cambiar.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Bien, despues de mucha documentacion he logrado hacer que funcione.

Dejo el codigo entero, aunque hace falta pulirlo un poco, espero que este tipo de respuesta no me haga acreedor a negativos. XD.

```
class ChatComents: JSQMessagesViewController {
var user: FIRUser?
var messages = [JSQMessage]()
var messagesStack = [JSQMessage]()
var avatars = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
var avatarsTapImage = Dictionary<String, UIImage>()
var avatarsUrl = Dictionary<String, String>()
var outgoingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage!
var incomingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage!
var senderImageUrl: String!
var batchMessages = true
var messagesBlockCant: UInt = 25
var numeroDeComentarios: Int?
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var imageRemoteURL: String?
//var currentUsername: String?
var messageRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
var currentUserAvatar = UIImageView()

// *** STEP 1: STORE FIREBASE REFERENCES
var messagesRef: FIRDatabaseReference!



private func setupBubbles() {

    let factory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
    outgoingBubbleImageView = factory.outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(
        UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleBlueColor())
    incomingBubbleImageView = factory.incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(
        UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleGreenColor()) //jsq_messageBubbleLightGrayColor
}
func convertDateFormater(date: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" // 2016-06-20 20:32:40 +0000
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")

    guard let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date) else {
        assert(false, "no date from string")
        return ""
    }

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy HH:mm"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    let timeStamp = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    print("fecha reformateada vale: ", timeStamp)
    return timeStamp
}


func setupFirebase() {
    // *** STEP 2: SETUP FIREBASE


    // *** STEP 4: RECEIVE MESSAGES FROM FIREBASE (limited to latest 25
    messageRef.queryLimitedToLast(messagesBlockCant).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let text = snapshot.value!["text"] as! String
        let senderId = snapshot.value!["senderId"] as! String
        let imageUrl = snapshot.value!["imageURL"] as! String
        let senderDisplayName = snapshot.value!["senderDisplayName"] as! String
        let fecha = snapshot.value!["fecha"] as! String
        print("fecha sin formato es: ", fecha) //  ....
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" //"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" // 2016-06-20 20:32:40 +0000
        let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fecha)

        let dateFormatter24Hrs = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter24Hrs.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z" // 2016-06-20 2311:16:48 p.m. +0000
        //let fechita = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fecha)
        print("La fecha final es: ", date, "del texto: ", text)


        let message =  JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, senderDisplayName: senderDisplayName, date: date, text: text)
        self.avatarsUrl.updateValue(imageUrl, forKey: senderId)
        print("avatarsUrl vale: ", self.avatarsUrl)
        self.messages.append(message)
        self.finishReceivingMessage()
    })
}

func sendMessage(text: String!, senderId: String!) {
    // *** STEP 3: ADD A MESSAGE TO FIREBASE
    let components = calendar.components([.Day , .Month , .Year], fromDate: date)

    let year =  components.year
    let month = components.month
    let day = components.day
    let fechaComentario = String(String(day) + "/" + String(month) + "/" + String(year))
    print("Fecha del comentario: ", fechaComentario)
    messageRef.childByAutoId().setValue([
        "text": text, //
        "votes": 0,
        "senderDisplayName": senderDisplayName,
        "senderId": senderId, //
        "nombreEntidad": Variable.currentObject,
        "imageURL": senderImageUrl, //
        "fecha": fechaComentario //
        ])
}
func setupAvatarImage(name: String, imageUrl: String?, incoming: Bool, initials: String) {
    print("el name vale: ", name)
    print("el initial vale: ", initials)
    if let stringUrl = imageUrl {
        if let url = NSURL(string: stringUrl) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                let diameter = incoming ? UInt(collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize.width) : UInt(collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize.width)
                print("diametro es: ", diameter)

                let avatarImage = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImageWithImage(image, diameter: diameter)

                avatars[name] = avatarImage
                avatarsTapImage[name] = image

                return
            }
        }
    }
    setupAvatarColor(name, incoming: incoming, initials: initials)
}

func setupAvatarColor(name: String, incoming: Bool, initials: String) {
    let diameter = incoming ? UInt(collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize.width) : UInt(collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize.width)

    let rgbValue = name.hash
    let r = CGFloat(Float((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0)
    let g = CGFloat(Float((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0)
    let b = CGFloat(Float(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0)
    let color = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 0.5)

    let nameLength = initials.characters.count

    let initialsName : String? = initials.substringToIndex(senderId.startIndex.advancedBy(min(3, nameLength)))
    print("INICIALES: ", initialsName)



    let userImage = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImageWithUserInitials(initialsName, backgroundColor: color, textColor: UIColor.blackColor(), font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(CGFloat(13)), diameter: diameter)


    avatars[name] = userImage
    avatarsTapImage[name] = userImage.avatarHighlightedImage

}

func loadMore() {
    print("Load earlier messages!")
    //setupFirebase()
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.springinessEnabled = false


    messagesBlockCant += 25
            var contador = 1
    // *** STEP 4: RECEIVE MESSAGES FROM FIREBASE (limited to latest 25
    messageRef.queryLimitedToLast(messagesBlockCant).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        self.collectionView.infiniteScrollingView.startAnimating()
        let diferencia = self.numeroDeComentarios! -  self.messages.count
        if  (diferencia != 0) // (self.numeroDeComentarios! >= self.messages.count) //|| (diferencia != 0)
        {
            //self.collectionView.showsInfiniteScrolling = false
            let oldBottomOffset = self.collectionView.contentSize.height - self.collectionView.contentOffset.y

            //print("Este mensaje no deberia aparecer si diferencia es 0: ", diferencia)
            let text = snapshot.value!["text"] as! String
            let senderId = snapshot.value!["senderId"] as! String
            let imageUrl = snapshot.value!["imageURL"] as! String
            let senderDisplayName = snapshot.value!["senderDisplayName"] as! String
            let fecha = snapshot.value!["fecha"] as! String
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" //"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" // 2016-06-20 20:32:40 +0000
            let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fecha)

            let message =  JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, senderDisplayName: senderDisplayName, date: date, text: text)


            self.avatarsUrl.updateValue(imageUrl, forKey: senderId)

            if diferencia > 24
            {
                if contador <= 25 {
                    self.messagesStack.insert(message, atIndex: 0)
                     print("La fecha final es: ", date, "del texto: ", text)
                    //print("contador: ", contador)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if contador <= diferencia+1
                {
                    self.messagesStack.insert(message, atIndex: 0)
                    print("self.messagesStack contiene: ", text)
                    print("text agregado cuando ya no es multiplo de 25: ", diferencia)
                    print("contador diferente a 25: ", contador)
                }
            }

            contador += 1

            if contador == 26{
                if diferencia > 24
                {
                    for limiteMax in 0...24{
                        //print("limiteMax vale: ", limiteMax)
                        //print("messagesStack.count vale: ", self.messagesStack.count)
                        let traspasoValores = self.messagesStack[limiteMax]
                        self.messages.insert(traspasoValores, atIndex: 0)
                        self.finishReceivingMessage()
                    }
                } else{

                    if diferencia != 0 {
                        for limiteMax in 1...diferencia {
                            let traspasoValores = self.messagesStack[limiteMax]
                            self.messages.insert(traspasoValores, atIndex: 0)
                            self.finishReceivingMessage()
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            self.finishReceivingMessageAnimated(false)
            self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.collectionView.contentSize.height - oldBottomOffset)


            self.collectionView.infiniteScrollingView.stopAnimating()

            self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.springinessEnabled = false


        }
        else{
            print("No hay mas comentarios que mostrar")
            self.collectionView.infiniteScrollingView.stopAnimating()

            self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.springinessEnabled = false
           self.collectionView.showsInfiniteScrolling = false
        }
        self.collectionView.infiniteScrollingView.stopAnimating()


    })


}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //inputToolbar!.contentView!.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    self.inputToolbar.removeFromSuperview()
    //automaticallyScrollsToMostRecentMessage = true
    self.showLoadEarlierMessagesHeader = true
    self.collectionView.loadEarlierMessagesHeaderTextColor = UIColor.blackColor()


                  // Infinite scrolling


    //navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Atras"
    setupBubbles()
    senderId = (senderId != nil) ? senderId : "Anonymous"
    let profileImageUrl = imageRemoteURL
    if let urlString = profileImageUrl {
        setupAvatarImage(senderId, imageUrl: urlString as String, incoming: false, initials: senderDisplayName)
        senderImageUrl = urlString as String
    } else {
        setupAvatarColor(senderId, incoming: false, initials: senderDisplayName)
        senderImageUrl = ""
    }

    setupFirebase()

       }

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        //self.collectionView.triggerPullToRefresh()
        Variable.refComment.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        let numeroDeComents = snapshot.childrenCount
        self.numeroDeComentarios = Int(numeroDeComents)
        print("y el numero de comentarios en viewDidAppear es: ", self.numeroDeComentarios!)
        }, withCancelBlock: { error in
            print(error.description)
    })

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}

override func didPressSendButton(button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!,
                                 senderDisplayName: String!, date: NSDate!) {

    let components = calendar.components([.Day , .Month , .Year], fromDate: date)
    let year =  components.year
    let month = components.month
    let day = components.day
    let fechaComentario = String(String(day) + "/" + String(month) + "/" + String(year))
    print("Fecha del comentario: ", fechaComentario)
    let fechaComment = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(fechaComment)
    print("convertedDate vale: ", convertedDate)
    let messageItem = [
        "text": text, //
        "votes": 0,
        "senderDisplayName": senderDisplayName,
        "senderId": senderId, //
        "nombreEntidad": Variable.currentObject,
        "imageURL": imageRemoteURL!, //
        "fecha": String(convertedDate) //
    ]
    messageRef.childByAutoId().setValue(messageItem)

    // 4
    JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound()

    // 5
    finishSendingMessage()
}


func didPressSendButton(button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, date: NSDate!) {
    JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound()

}

override func didPressAccessoryButton(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Camera pressed!")
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    print("Tapped message bubble!")
}

func dismissFullscreenImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, didTapAvatarImageView avatarImageView: UIImageView!, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    print("Tapped avatar!")
    let message = messages[indexPath.row]
    Variable.popupUsername = message.senderDisplayName
    Variable.popupImageProfile = avatarsTapImage[message.senderId]!
    Variable.popupImageProfileUrl = avatarsUrl[message.senderId]
    Variable.popupSenderId = message.senderId
    //Variable.popupLoveUserCant =
    //Variable.popupCommentUserCant =

    PopupController
        .create(self)
        .show(ProfileResumeVC.instance())

}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .None

}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    return messages[indexPath.item]
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item] // 1

    if message.senderId == senderId {
        return outgoingBubbleImageView
    } else { // 3
        return incomingBubbleImageView
    }

}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, attributedTextForCellTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> NSAttributedString! {
        let message = self.messages[indexPath.item]
        return JSQMessagesTimestampFormatter.sharedFormatter().attributedTimestampForDate(message.date)
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForCellTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return kJSQMessagesCollectionViewCellLabelHeightDefault

}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, header headerView: JSQMessagesLoadEarlierHeaderView!, didTapLoadEarlierMessagesButton sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Load earlier messages!")
           //setupFirebase()


    showLoadEarlierMessagesHeader = true

    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.springinessEnabled = false


    messagesBlockCant += 25
    var contador = 1
    // *** CONTANDO EL NUMERO DE COMENTARIOS




    // *** STEP 4: RECEIVE MESSAGES FROM FIREBASE (limited to latest 25
    messageRef.queryLimitedToLast(messagesBlockCant).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let diferencia = self.numeroDeComentarios! -  self.messages.count
        if  (diferencia != 0) // (self.numeroDeComentarios! >= self.messages.count) //|| (diferencia != 0)
        {
            let oldBottomOffset = self.collectionView.contentSize.height - self.collectionView.contentOffset.y


            let text = snapshot.value!["text"] as! String
            let senderId = snapshot.value!["senderId"] as! String
            let imageUrl = snapshot.value!["imageURL"] as! String
            let senderDisplayName = snapshot.value!["senderDisplayName"] as! String
            let fecha = snapshot.value!["fecha"] as! String

            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" //"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" // 2016-06-20 20:32:40 +0000
            let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fecha)

            let message =  JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, senderDisplayName: senderDisplayName, date: date, text: text)


            self.avatarsUrl.updateValue(imageUrl, forKey: senderId)
            if diferencia > 24
            {
                if contador <= 25 {
                    self.messagesStack.insert(message, atIndex: 0)
                    print("La fecha final es: ", date, "del texto: ", text)
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                if contador <= diferencia+1
                {
                    self.messagesStack.insert(message, atIndex: 0)
                    print("self.messagesStack contiene: ", text)
                    print("text agregado cuando ya no es multiplo de 25: ", diferencia)
                    print("contador diferente a 25: ", contador)
                }
            }

            contador += 1

            if contador == 26{
                if diferencia > 24
                {
                    for limiteMax in 0...24{
                        //print("limiteMax vale: ", limiteMax)
                        //print("messagesStack.count vale: ", self.messagesStack.count)
                        let traspasoValores = self.messagesStack[limiteMax]
                        self.messages.insert(traspasoValores, atIndex: 0)
                        self.finishReceivingMessage()
                    }
                } else{
                    print("No es exacto, debemos hacer algo aqui: ", diferencia)
                    if diferencia != 0 {
                        for limiteMax in 1...diferencia {
                            print("limiteMax vale en xxx: ", limiteMax)
                            print("messagesStack.count vale en xxx: ", self.messagesStack.count)
                            let traspasoValores = self.messagesStack[limiteMax]
                            self.messages.insert(traspasoValores, atIndex: 0)
                            self.finishReceivingMessage()
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            self.finishReceivingMessageAnimated(false)
            self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.collectionView.contentSize.height - oldBottomOffset)


            self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.springinessEnabled = false
                      }
        else{
            print("No hay mas comentarios que mostrar")
                            self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.springinessEnabled = false
            self.showLoadEarlierMessagesHeader = false
        }
                })





}



override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {

    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    var imageAvatar : JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource?
    for senderReferenceImage in avatars.keys where senderReferenceImage == message.senderId
    {

            imageAvatar = avatars[senderReferenceImage] as? JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource
           // print("Hola desde el primer Ford XD")
            return imageAvatar
    }

    for senderReferenceUrl in avatarsUrl.keys where senderReferenceUrl == message.senderId
    {

        print("message.senderId! vale: ", message.senderId!)
        print("avatarsUrl[senderReferenceUrl] vale: ", avatarsUrl[senderReferenceUrl]!)
        setupAvatarImage(message.senderId!,  imageUrl: avatarsUrl[senderReferenceUrl], incoming: true, initials: message.senderDisplayName)
        imageAvatar = avatars[senderReferenceUrl] as? JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource
        return imageAvatar

    }
    return JSQMessagesAvatarImage.avatarWithImage(self.currentUserAvatar.image)

}



override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    if message.senderId == senderId {
        cell.textView!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    } else {
        cell.textView!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    let attributes : [NSObject:AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:cell.textView!.textColor!, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: 1]
    cell.textView!.linkTextAttributes = attributes as AnyObject as! [String : AnyObject]

    return cell
}


// View  usernames above bubbles
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> NSAttributedString! {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item];

    // Sent by me, skip
    if message.senderId! == senderId {
        return nil
    }

    // Same as previous sender, skip
    if indexPath.item > 0 {
        let previousMessage = messages[indexPath.item - 1];
        if previousMessage.senderId == message.senderId {
            return NSAttributedString(string:message.senderDisplayName!)
        }
    }

    return NSAttributedString(string:message.senderDisplayName!)
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    // Sent by me, skip
    if message.senderId == senderId {
        return CGFloat(0.0);
    }

    // Same as previous sender, skip
    if indexPath.item > 0 {
        let previousMessage = messages[indexPath.item - 1];
        if previousMessage.senderId == message.senderId {
            return CGFloat(0.0);
        }
    }

    return kJSQMessagesCollectionViewCellLabelHeightDefault
}
```

}